# Remove disabled from button if all fields full and checkbox:checked

Tags: jquery

I use this code for add and remove :disabled from submit. But I know how make it for input with value, but how does it make for input:checked if the last filed is checkbox I don't understand. 
I need remove disabled if all input's value full and checkbox is checked

```js
 $('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $('.contact-form__window').find(':input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea,input[type="checkbox"]').keyup(function() { // monitor all inputs for changes
            var disable = false;
            $('.contact-form__window').find(':input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea,input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
                if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
            
                    disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
                    
                }
            });
            if(disable == true)
            $('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            else
            $('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').removeAttr("disabled");
        });
```

```css
.button-red {
background: red;
display: block
color: #fff;
}

.button-red:disabled {
 background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="contact-form__window">
<input type="text">
<input type="email">
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="checkbox">

<input type="submit" value="send" class="button-red">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire the event on `input[type=checkbox]` to see if it is checked then the button will be enabled otherwise it remains disabled.
Try below code-

```js
$('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.contact-form__window').on('keyup, change', 'input, textarea', function() { // monitor all inputs for changes
  var disable = false;
  $('.contact-form__window').find('input,textarea').each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
    if (!disable && ($(el).val().trim() == '')) {
      disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
    }
    else if(!disable && ($(el).attr('type') == 'checkbox') && (!$(el).prop('checked'))){
      disable = true
    }
  });
  if (disable == true)
    $('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  else
    $('.contact-form__window').find('.button-red').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
.button-red {
  background: red;
  display: block color: #fff;
}

.button-red:disabled {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="contact-form__window">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="email">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox">

  <input type="submit" value="send" class="button-red">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, i made it so, but if one of the field is empty and checkbox:checked submit disabled removes but it is wrong (  I need remove disabled if all field are full and checkbox checked

Comment: sorry for late reply but I have updated my answer please check. @SergeyWebster

Comment: Also, I have optimized your code too. @SergeyWebster